# FAQ wordpress plugin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I am looking for a Wordpress FAQ plugin that functions in the same way as 95% of the ones out there but simply has a category selector, secondary filter and search.

This exact feature can be seen on this website - https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-of-clans/?p=all

When it displays results i just want it to display them as an accordion like most out there.
http://radykal.de/wordpress-plugins/superior-faq/#faq/vivamus-elementum-semper-nisi-aenean-vulputate-eleifend-tellus

Does anyone know of a plugin that can do this?

Just can't believe there's not one out there and will cost a fortune to have built comprehensively.

Many many thanks for any leads or ideas.

Kind regards

Oli

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/html5-responsive-faq/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-faqs/

I have used both of these previously, and they work well. I am not sure they are 100% what you are after but it may point you in the right direction.

http://www.wpsuperstars.net/faq-plugins-for-wordpress/